# Узнать UUID bluetooth службы

Tags: android, phonegap, cordova, bluetooth

Пишу приложение на cordova. Нужен обмен данных между 2-мя устройствами через bluetooth. Нашел много плагинов, но не могу заставить их работать.

Насколько я понял, я не верно передаю UUID службы, с которой я буду работать. Но собственно вопрос:

Как узнать UUID? Или его надо самому придумать?

Код вызова

```
var uuid = '00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
var address = '00:45:DA:B4:07:BF';

networking.bluetooth.connect(address, uuid, function (socketId) {
    alert('Success. ID - '+socketId);
}, function (errorMessage) {
    alert('Connection failed: ' + errorMessage);
});
```

Ошибка, которую получаю

```
connection failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Comment: Какие у вас ошибки? Можно взглянуть на ваш код?

Comment: получаю такую ошибку "connection failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

Comment: Ошибку в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: добавил получаемую ошибку

Comment: прошу помощи с вопросом, так ничего и не решил